# StringContent Vs FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#, http-post

I have a URL I want to post a body with parameters to such in the form of data="blahblahblah".  However, my "blahblahblah" in this case is a full fledged XML, I simple it down to something like below:

```
      <Parent id="1">
         <Child id="1"/>
      </Parent>
```

I can get this to work fine with HTTPClient FormUrlEncodedContent using the following approach.

```
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("data", XMLBody));
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        HttpResponseMessage sResponse = await sClient.PostAsync(action.URL, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Now I want to get this to work with StringContent.   **To basically sending xml as part of a parameter value, and that xml contains the "="** .  The code below doesn't work, as in I can post it but the server isn't recognize the xml data.  Am I doing something wrong here?

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(action.Body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage sResponse = await sClient.PostAsync(action.URL, content ).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found it, I have to manually put in the data= part.

```
StringContent content = new StringContent("data="+ HttpUtility.UrlEncode(action.Body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage sResponse = await sClient.PostAsync(action.URL, content ).ConfigureAwait(false);
```