# Is it possible to increase the max URI lenght in HttpClient? (Invalid URI: The uri string is too long)

Tags: .net, url, uri, dotnet-httpclient, .net-5

I am using an `HttpClient` in `Dotnet 5` and try to create a query with a very long URI. I get this exception

`Invalid URI: The uri string is too long`

I tried to figure out where it comes from and it seems it boils down to [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/84268942a88c85f1a3485d1db42abee5b879cbae/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L38) with a constant:

```
internal const int c_MaxUriBufferSize = 0xFFF0;
```

It seems that it is actually impossible to have a URL longer than 64K, but there is perhaps something I did not figure out?

Comment: Why do you need such long uri?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient: The uri string is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440631/httpclient-the-uri-string-is-too-long)

Comment: @PeterCsala Hi, no, that answers a completely different question ironically

Answer (score 2):

In short: you can't.

If you look at the source of `Uri` then it becomes clear why.

- In case of .NET Core the Uri's source code resides in [this file](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs).

Inside its `GetException` [method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L627) it translates `ParsingError.SizeLimit` [into](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L645) an `UriFormatException`.

- The related resource entry can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/Resources/Strings.resx#L174).

So, if we look at the code of the `Uri` to see when it fails with `ParsingError.SizeLimit` then we will find these:

- [ParseScheme](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L1823)
- [GetHostViaCustomSyntax](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L2477)
- [ParseRemaining](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L3272)
- [ParseRemaining](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L3408)
- [ParseRemaining](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L3465)
- [CheckAuthorityHelper](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L3974)

In the first two cases the limit is checked against `c_MaxUriBufferSize` ([1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L38)), which is defined as this:

```cs
internal const int c_MaxUriBufferSize = 0xFFF0;
```

In later cases the limit is checked against `ushort.MaxValue`.

Unfortunately none of them are changeable.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that's the same I figured...